# Return an object with a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to return an object with a function in React JS.

I have the next code :

```
let filters = [
  {name: "PRICE_RANGE", values: [{active: "true", low: 10000, high: 21000}]}  
]


getFilterValues(filters, filterName){
        return filters.filter(f => {
            if(f.name === filterName) {
                return {low: f.values.low, high: f.values.high};
            }
        })
    }



<PriceFilter values={this.getFilterValues(filters, "PRICE_RANGE")} />
```

The result that I get is

`{name: "PRICE_RANGE", values: [{active: "true", low: 10000, high: 21000}]}`

But I want something like this :

`{low: 10000, high: 21000}`

Any advice why I'm getting whole array back and not the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this snippet will be useful.

Create a generic function which will accept the `key` which you want to filter.
Create an object and populate it with `low` & `high` value if it matches.
Return the object.

```
  let filters = [{
  name: "PRICE_RANGE",
  values: [{
    active: "true",
    low: 10000,
    high: 21000
  }]
}]

function filterMe(key){
 var newObj={};
   filters.filter(function(item,index) {
      if(item.name === key){
         newObj.low=item.values[0].low;
         newObj.high=item.values[0].high
       }
    })
    return newObj;
}
console.log(filterMe("PRICE_RANGE"))
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/L2tn6grc/1/)

Answer (score 1):

`filter` works a bit differently than you are using it. If you return anything truthy from the inner function, the element is considered valid.

Here is an example:

```
function isBigEnough(value) {
  return value >= 10;
}
var filtered = [12, 5, 8, 130, 44].filter(isBigEnough);
// filtered is [12, 130, 44]
```

For your example, this means that by calling `return {low: f.values.low, high: f.values.high};` you are just telling `filter` that the current element in `filters` is valid and should be kept.

If you only want the `values` member, you could write code similar to this:

```
getFilterValues(filters, filterName){
    return filters.filter(f => {
        if(f.name === filterName) {
            return true;
        }
    }).map(f => {
        return f.values;
    });
}
```

This code filters the array and then extracts and returns the `values` member.

Comment: I still do not get the result I want. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o93Lm0rc/95)

Comment: I tried to give a general example. Use this for your exact usecase: https://jsfiddle.net/o93Lm0rc/96/

Answer (score 1):

```js
function getFilterValues(filters, filterName) {
  return filters
    .filter(f => f.name === filterName) // get the  chosen filter
    .map(f => f.values)[0] // retrieve values from the object
    .map(v => ({
      low: v.low,
      high: v.high
    })) // get only low and high props
}

//////////// test case ///////////////////////////////////////////

let filters = [{
  name: "PRICE_RANGE",
  values: [{
    active: "true",
    low: 10000,
    high: 21000
  }]
}]

let filtered = getFilterValues(filters, "PRICE_RANGE")
document.write(JSON.stringify(filtered))
```